# Error in the where part of my MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Please help I have no clue what is wrong here. I have submitted the error and the actual query below.

Error:

```
UPDATE `WWM_Login` SET `Username`='RyzeAlchemist',`Email`='smadger@live.co.uk',`FirstName`='test',`MiddleName`='test',`LastName`='test',`DiscordID`='@RyzeAlchemist#6043',`P_openCompletedOrders`=1,`P_openCurrentOrders`=1,`P_openRequestedOrders`=1,`P_openCreateAnOrder`=1,`P_OpenEditUsers`=0,`P_CreateStaff`=1,`P_CreateClient`= WHERE UserID = 9
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE UserID = 9' at line 1

Query:

```
"UPDATE `WWM_Login` SET `Username`='$uid',`Email`='$email',`FirstName`='$firstname',`MiddleName`='$middlename',`LastName`='$lastname',`DiscordID`='$DiscordID',`P_openCompletedOrders`=$field[1],`P_openCurrentOrders`=$field[2],`P_openRequestedOrders`=$field[3],`P_openCreateAnOrder`=$field[4],`P_OpenEditUsers`=$field[5],`P_CreateStaff`=$field[6],`P_CreateClient`=$field[7] WHERE UserID = $id"
```

Comment: If you used prepared statements with parameter binding, you'd skip over issues like this.

Comment: you have missed value for `P_CreateClient`, seems like `$field[7]` is not having any values which result query into `P_CreateClient = WHERE UserID = 9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be towards the end of your query:

```
`P_CreateClient`= WHERE
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
`P_CreateClient`='x' WHERE
```

Where x is the value you want to set

Comment: Thank you so much I am an idiot for not spotting that!

Comment: Happens to us all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Encase your variables in single quotes, like so:

```
P_CreateStaff`= '$field[6]'
```

This way, if there is an empty to NULL value it will take it as such. I see some of your variables are encased in signle quotes, but that particular variable is not so when there is no value MySQL is trying to look for a value equal to WHERE, so it's taking your WHERE clause as the condition for P_CreateStaff. To avoid this, encase all your variables in single quotes.